# Intellisense for imported PropTypes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webstorm, react-proptypes

Because of code redundancy reasons, I put the PropTypes for my entities in separate files like:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export const costCenterBookingPropTypes = PropTypes.shape({
    errorState: PropTypes.bool,
    costCenter: PropTypes.string,
    customerName: PropTypes.string,
    zipCode: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    city: PropTypes.string,
    startTime: PropTypes.string,
    endTime: PropTypes.string,
    drivingTimeActive: PropTypes.string,
    drivingTimePassive: PropTypes.string,
    breakTime: PropTypes.string,
    loadingTime: PropTypes.string,
    workingTime: PropTypes.string
});
```

It is working well but when I define my PropTypes this way and import it into a component and use it like:

```
DayOverviewTableDataRow.propTypes = {
    costCenterBooking: costCenterBookingPropTypes
};
```

Then I got no intellisense/autocomplete for my props like errorState, zipCode and so on.

Is that a known issue or did I make a mistake? I'm using WebStorm as IDE if that is important.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are describing is only achievable with TypeScript and you'll have to do some (pretty heavy) code refactoring.

Check out this Medium article: [React, TypeScript and defaultProps dilemma](https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/react-typescript-and-defaultprops-dilemma-ca7f81c661c7)

Comment: Don't post links as answer. What if the page become unavailable and someone is looking for the answer ?